# Sharing IClaimsPrincipal/FedAuth Cookie with .Net Core Project

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, ws-federation

I have an ASP.NET identity server app uses Federated Authentication.Now We are developing.Net Core 2.2 web app to integrate with the identity server. But there is some issue we couldn't figure out.
I couldn't get ClaimsIdentity in a secure cookie. I try to decrypt with System.Security.Cryptography.Xml but I couldn't succeed it. How I can decrypt cookie and reach the claims in the token?

> Cookie example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SecurityContextToken p1:Id="_208ff796-8c41-430a-b001-4b40eb162c83-72BB0DCC1AA7D75C50AA3B080D5BFE99"
    xmlns:p1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512">
    <Identifier>urn:uuid:c735123c-5570-49e8-a49d-8f3ce91a6aa9</Identifier>          
    <Cookie
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/security">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
   </Cookie>
</SecurityContextToken>
```

thanks

Comment: Any updates on that? I am also having the same issue. I saw some solutions but is all on Net Full framework (http://michaelkc.tumblr.com/post/25012272361/decoding-the-wif-session-security-token-with-a), I would like some solutions on net core too. Did you have any success?

Comment: Bump. We have the same scenario. Trying to break out our monolith into smaller parts using dotnet core. Would be nice if we could have the auth cookie "just work" in the dotnet core parts.